# pandas plotting timedelta with yerr fails

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to plot a pandas series like so:

```
s = pd.Series(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    index=pd.TimedeltaIndex(
        ["0 days 00:30:00", "0 days 01:00:00", "0 days 01:30:00", "0 days 02:00:00", "0 days 02:30:00"],
        dtype="timedelta64[ns]",
        freq=None,
    ),
)

s.plot(yerr=s)
```

Without `yerr=s` the above works fine. When I pass in `yerr=s` I get:

```
...
     16 @set_module('numpy')
     17 def asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):
     18     """Convert the input to an array.
     19 
     20     Parameters
   (...)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta
```

If we defined `s` without timedelta indices, it would work:

```
s = pd.Series(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
)
```

[image]

What's going on here? How can I add the error bars to my line graph?

Comment: Are you trying to set_xticks()? What exactly is you wanted result graph?

Comment: `s.plot(yerr=s)` works fine on my system with Pandas 1.1.3, Matplotlib 3.2.2, Numpy 1.21.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code works fine for me... this means you'll probably need to look into more details such as your pandas, numpy, and matplotlib versions.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    index=pd.TimedeltaIndex(
        ["0 days 00:30:00", "0 days 01:00:00", "0 days 01:30:00", "0 days 02:00:00", "0 days 02:30:00"],
        dtype="timedelta64[ns]",
        freq=None,
    ),
)

s.plot(yerr=s)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]